# How to get all the values in a column from a database in python (SQLAlchemy)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a table called draws. All I want to do is get the column 'user_id' as an array, in order from the 'id' column (top to bottom).

The ID column just numbers each row.

I've written this:
user_id = Draw.query.order_by(desc('id')).all()

This query gets every column though right? I just want the information in the 'user_id' column

Answer (score 0):

user_id = Draw.query.with_entities(Draw.user_id).order_by(desc(Draw.id)).all()

[With entities explanation from the docs.](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.with_entities)

Alternatively you can just do a list comprehension on the query you already have -- something like:

user_ids = [d.user_id for d in user_id]

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
 from sqlalchemy import desc

 db.session.query(Draw.user_id).order_by(desc(Draw.id)).all()
```